# JavaFX custom node not rendering children

Tags: java, javafx, components

I have created a custom component which is basically a vbox with more components inside. However when I include it on the HomeView.fxml the component's children are nowhere to be seen. Each individual internal component is null, causing a NullPointerException on the binding part on HomeController. What am I missing?

HomeView.fxml

```
<StackPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="views.home.HomeController">
    <BorderPane>
        <center>Placeholder</center>
    </BorderPane>
    <SidePane fx:id="sidePane" maxWidth="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: cyan;" translateX="200.0" StackPane.alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" />
</StackPane>
```

HomeController.java

```
public class HomeController implements Initializable {

    private final HomeViewModel viewModel;

    @FXML private SidePane sidePane;

    public HomeController(HomeViewModel viewModel) {
        this.viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        // Bind side pane - NullPointerException here, that's why it is commented out
        // sidePane.imageProperty().bindBidirectional(viewModel.selectedPlatform().image());
        // sidePane.nameProperty().bindBidirectional(viewModel.selectedPlatform().name());
        // sidePane.identifierProperty().bind(viewModel.selectedPlatform().id().asString());
    }

}
```

SidePane.fxml

```
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.Region"
         fx:controller="viewscomponents.sidepane.SidePane"
     xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
     xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
     prefWidth="200" maxWidth="200">
    <childrenUnmodifiable>
        <VBox>
            <ImageView fx:id="image" />
            <Label text="Name:" />
            <TextField fx:id="name" />
            <HBox>
                <Label alignment="BOTTOM_RIGHT" text="id: " />
                <Label fx:id="id" />
            </HBox>
        </VBox>
    </childrenUnmodifiable>
</fx:root>
```

SidePane.java

```
public class SidePane extends Region {

    @FXML private ImageView image;
    @FXML private TextField name;
    @FXML private Label id;

    public ObjectProperty<Image> imageProperty() {
        return image.imageProperty();
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name.textProperty();
    }

    public StringProperty identifierProperty() {
        return id.textProperty();
    }

}
```

Comment: [mcve] please .. including imports and application

Comment: You never load `SidePane.fxml` anywhere. See the example of this patten in the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components)

Answer (score 0):

As James_D stated in his comment, you never load the fxml file of your custom control. Also I think it does not work with `Region` and you should not specify a controller in the fxml file. It should work like this:

**SidePane.java**

```java
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

import java.io.IOException;

public class SidePane extends VBox {

    @FXML
    private ImageView image;
    @FXML
    private TextField name;
    @FXML
    private Label id;

    public SidePane() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource("SidePane.fxml"));
        loader.setRoot(this);
        loader.setController(this);
        loader.load();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Image> imageProperty() {
        return image.imageProperty();
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name.textProperty();
    }

    public StringProperty identifierProperty() {
        return id.textProperty();
    }
}
```

**SidePane.fxml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<fx:root type="VBox"
         xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
         xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
         prefWidth="200" maxWidth="200">
    <ImageView fx:id="image"/>
    <Label text="Name:"/>
    <TextField fx:id="name"/>
    <HBox>
        <Label alignment="BOTTOM_RIGHT" text="id: "/>
        <Label fx:id="id"/>
    </HBox>
</fx:root>
```

Comment: But then the SidePane is exposing the Vbox methods, is this common practice? Or is there any alternative?

Comment: You can put the VBox in a Region, and then have SidePane be of type Region.  This would hide VBox methods.

Comment: @DaveB Can you create an example with the use of `Region` and share it with us please?